# How anonymous are Ether transactions?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin, anonymity

I read some sources that say transactions are anonymous, some that say they are semi-anonymous, and some that say they are not anonymous at all. In what ways are the transactions anonymous and in what ways are they not anonymous?

And how does that differ from Bitcoin's pseudonymous transactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference compared to Bitcoin is that they do not use change addresses. This reduces anonymity a little bit (change addresses don't help much if someone is serious about tracking you). If you keep your account address anonymous (by not linking it to known addresses through transactions) it has otherwise the same pseudonymous properties of Bitcoin. This is an area of active research for ethereum so anonymity will increase with future versions of the protocol (and it will also add the ability to use change addresses).