# Is it possible to transfer an ENS address to an anonymous owner?

Tags: ens

If I wanted to transfer an ENS address I won to an anonymous / unlinkable owner, is that possible?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you have in mind there? Not sure what you are trying to do - but it sounds wrong ..-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How anonymous are Ether transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-anonymous-are-ether-transactions)

Comment: I basically want to delink an .eth address I won with my Mist Wallet.  Is that possible?

Comment: If you never associated your wallet address with your real name, your account is already anonymous i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer an ENS address to anyone or anything, whether there's an obvious link or not.

However, this will not prevent someone from reviewing the blockchain to see who originally bought said address.

Answer (score 0):

I recently contacted ENS and asked them this same question. Their reply:

> Hey! There isn't really a good way to do that right now
> unfortunately. To transfer a name, you just change the Registrant and
> the Controller to the new Ethereum account. Who sent it will still be
> visible on the chain. Someone could maybe use a mixer or something,
> but we don't have that setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Somewhat.

0. Where 0xEth1 is a known non-anonymous/KYC address (bought eth on Coinbase)
1. Set up a fresh eth address (0xEth2) with proper OpSec.
2. Transfer the ENS Domain name from (0xEth1) to (0xEth2), maybe hold a fake sale on OpenSea.
3. Burn the original eth address, never use it again.
4. Keep (0xEth2) segregated as much as possible from KYC services. Dont use any KYC services to buy eth and send it directly to that account. Might even want to do a 2 step with some privacy coin or feature for all incoming eth. Limited interaction.
5. Say you sold it if anyone ask.

The only thing that makes an account anonymous is the fact that...

- A. You can create an unlimited amount of addresses.
- B. There are no strong links between that address and some KYC info.